# SQL Server Login Successful When It Shouldn't Be

Tags: security, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

Earlier today I restored a database from our DEV environment onto our TEST environment. After restoring, I removed all of the logins (both NT and SQL) from the database. Much to my dismay, one of the users from the database in the DEV environment is able to get into the TEST database. I have confirmed this through both looking at his screen confirming his connection and using Profiler and watching his logins.

He cannot get to any other databases on TEST which is expected.

Although it shouldn't matter, DEV is 2008R2 and TEST is 2012.

Has anyone ever seen anything like this before? Is it possible something I cannot see has "come over with the backup" and is still there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a distinction between database *users*, and server *logins*.  Restoring a database should have no impact on the login (username and password) that the individual used to connect to the server...

If you only removed users from the database that you restored, the individual may still have permission to the database because of the access granted to their login (such as sysadmin).

Check what logins exist at the server level, instead of at the database level.  Also watch out for the `BUILTIN\Administrator` role at the server level, which may be granting the individual access because he is an administrator at the windows server level.

Comment: This was my thinking too.  All server logins that are a member of the `sysadmin` server role automatically map to the built-in database user `dbo` which has all permissions.  This is why a member of the `sysadmin` role automatically can connect to any database on the server.

Comment: I tracked this down after a couple of days. The user in question was the creator of the database. This explained why he had rights in DEV but not in TEST. I dropped the database in TEST and recreated it through scripts under my rights and it worked fine.